# Intellij Documentation background color

Tags: intellij-idea

I used to like the old yellow background. After an update, I am getting it as white. Could not find a way to change it in the setting.

[image]

How can I change it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find it in the settings here: `Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | General`
Then look for `Popups and Hints > Documentation` in the list box. I believe the previous/old color had the same value as `Popups and Hints > Information hint`: FDFEE2